# Как в mongoose обновить не все поля?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

в таблице несколько полей, например:

- id
- name
- value
- order

требуется обновить только `value`, делаю так:

```
db.tables.update( { "id", 5 }, { "value" : 10 } )
```

после этого в записи остается только 2 поля `id` и `value`

почему удалились остальные поля, и как правильно обновлять только 1 поле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формат запроса update:

```
update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>
   }
)
```

**Параметр `<query>`**

Условие должно быть: `{id: 5}`.
А то, что ты написал, это `{id: id, 5: 5}`

```
db.tables.update({ "id": 5 }, { "value" : 10 })
```

---

**Параметр `<update>`**

Плоский объект(`{поле: значение, ...}`) в качестве второго параметра используется для замены документа целиком.

Для обновления части полей документа, нужно использовать операторы, например `$set`:

```
db.tables.update({ "id": 5 }, {'$set': {value: 10}})
```